SMS Message Numbers
With respect to this post (and several others) from several years ago:

How to read SMS using AT on an embedded system with limited memory?

How do I learn the identifier of the next message to read?  (If it matters, I'm using a Cinterion TX62-W chip.)
If I have already read messages (AT+CMGR=0, AT+CMGR=1, AT+CMGR=2) and deleted them (AT+CMGD=0, AT+CMGD=1, AT+CMGD=2), I would expect the next to be 3.  Can ask the modem for this number?
I've searched the post above but didn't want to hijack it.  I've tried a series of AT+CMxx commands.
Thanks, Mike
